# Dynamically Creating / Implementing Data in A Table with a 2D Array in Javascript/Html

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, dynamic

The goal I am trying to achieve is to dynamically create a table with data based off of the info from a 2D array. I've seen examples of table creation with 1D arrays, but I can't seem to wrap around creating it with 2D. Furthermore, once this table is created, I need to be able to manipulate it, for example deleting a row with insignificant information etc. I like to use a nested for loop for this. This needs to be created with Javascript / Html.
The table for example :

```
|item   | price | description|

|chicken | $20  | yummy |
```

And the array [0][0] is chicken, [0][1] is $20, [0][2] is yummy.
Any help / leads are appreciated!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a nested for loop:

```
let myArray = [['chicken', '$20', 'yummy']];
let myTable = '<table>';

for(let row = 0; row < myArray.length; row++){

    myTable += '<tr>'; // Create a row
    for(let col = 0; col < myArray[row].length; col++){
        myTable += `<td>${myArray[row][col]}</td>`; // Create a cell with the data
    }
    myTable += '</tr>'; // Close the row

}

myTable += '</table>'; // Finally close the table
```

This should create you a table with the array values.

Answer (score 0):

Below uses strictly dom manipulation to build your table, creating the necessary elements (i.e. HTML, TBODY, THEAD, TR, TD, TH) and building the structure over the course of a loop.

The performance of doing so can be improved, but this depends on how big your table (and the content of it) is.  Doing string concatenation and then binding to the dom in most cases will be faster, except for very large tables.  There are also other disadvantages to using string interpolation, such as escaping certain characters (dom manipulation handles this for you).

Only you can determine how big/small your table is and make the judgement.

### DOM Manipulation

```js
'use strict';

let arr = [
    ['item', 'price', 'description'],
    ['chicken', '$20', 'yummy']
  ],
  doc = document;

// Create DOM elements
let table = doc.createElement('table'),
  thead = doc.createElement('thead'),
  tbody = doc.createElement('tbody');

// Create cells and rows
arr.forEach((data, i) => {
  let tr = doc.createElement('tr');

  let container = tbody;
  let cell_type = 'td';
  if (i == 0) {
    container = thead;
    cell_type = 'th';
  }

  // Create and attach cells to row
  data.forEach(text => {
    let td = doc.createElement(cell_type);
    td.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(text));
    tr.appendChild(td);
  });

  // Attach TR to THEAD/TBODY
  container.appendChild(tr);
});

// Attach THEAD/TBODY to TABLE
table.appendChild(thead);
table.appendChild(tbody);

// Append Table to Document
doc.querySelector('body').appendChild(table);
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin-top: 2rem;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: .25rem;
}

th {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

### String Concatenation

```js
'use strict';

let arr = [
  ['item', 'price', 'description'],
  ['chicken', '$20', 'yummy']
];

// Build Rows
let rows = arr.map((data, i) => {
  let type = i == 0 ? 'th' : 'td';
  let cells = data.map(text => `<${type}>${text}</${type}>`)
  return `<tr>${cells.join('')}</tr>`;
});

// Build Table
let table = `<table>
  <thead>${rows.shift()}</thead>
  <tbody>${rows.join('')}</tbody>
</table>`;

// Append Table to Document
document.querySelector('body').innerHTML += table;
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin-top: 2rem;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: .25rem;
}

th {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

Comment: Your code seems to work pretty nicely with my table. I'm eager to use this method, as I'm not sure how I would be able to manipulate the table. Is the way you showed able to do stuff like, remove rows, sort, etc?

Comment: No.  If you want any advanced feature set, I recommend you see a third party library like DataTables (jQuery-dependent).

Answer (score 0):

Do it dynamically with Vanilla and ES6

```js
const food = [{
  Item: "chicken",
  Price: "$20",
  Description: "buck,buck,,,,, buck,,, buckAHHHH yumm"
}, {
  Item: "Beef",
  Price: "$20",
  Description: "Moo yumm"
}, {
  Item: "Dog",
  Price: "$20",
  Description: "woof-woof yumm"
}, {
  Item: "Cat",
  Price: "$20",
  Description: "meow-meow yumm"
}];

function tableCreate(items) {
  let lables = items.reduce((s, o) => [...new Set([...s, ...Object.keys(o)])], []);
  items.unshift(lables);
  let body = document.body,
    tbl = document.createElement('table');
  tbl.style.width = '100px';
  tbl.style.border = '1px solid black';
  for (let [i, index] of items.entries()) {
    let tr = tbl.insertRow();
    for (let j in items[i]) {
      let td = tr.insertCell();
      td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(items[i][j]));
      td.style.border = '1px solid black';
    }
  }
  body.appendChild(tbl);
  tbl.rows[0].style.fontWeight = 'bold';
}

tableCreate(food);
```

And you can modify it like so

```js
const food = [{
  Item: "chicken",
  Price: "$20",
  Description: "buck,buck,,,,, buck,,, buckAHHHH yumm"
}, {
  Item: "Beef",
  Price: "$20",
  Description: "Moo yumm"
}, {
  Item: "Dog",
  Price: "$20",
  Description: "woof-woof yumm"
}, {
  Item: "Cat",
  Price: "$20",
  Description: "meow-meow yumm"
}];

function tableCreate(items) {
  let lables = items.reduce((s, o) => [...new Set([...s, ...Object.keys(o)])], []);
  items.unshift(lables);
  let body = document.body,
    tbl = document.createElement('table');
  tbl.style.width = '100px';
  tbl.style.border = '1px solid black';
  for (let [i, index] of items.entries()) {
    let tr = tbl.insertRow();
    for (let j in items[i]) {
      let td = tr.insertCell();
      td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(items[i][j]));
      td.style.border = '1px solid black';
    }
  }
  body.appendChild(tbl);
  tbl.rows[0].style.fontWeight = 'bold';
}



const modify = {
  remove(from, val) {
    for (let [i, product] of from.entries()) {
      if (product.Item === val) {
        console.log(i)
        from.splice(i, 1);
        console.log(from)
      }
    }
  },
  removeOnLengthsLargerThan(from, val) {
    for (let [i, product] of from.entries()) {
      if (product.Description) {
        if (product.Description.length > val) {
          from.splice(i, 1);
        }
      }
    }
  },
  shorten(from, val) {
    for (let [i, product] of from.entries()) {
      if (product.Description) {
        if (product.Description.length > val) {
          product.Description = product.Description.substr(0, val);

        }
      }
    }
  }
}

modify.shorten(food, 10);
console.log('shorten',food);
modify.remove(food, 'chicken');
console.log('remove',food);
modify.removeOnLengthsLargerThan(food, 10)
console.log('removeOnLengthsLargerThan',food);
tableCreate(food);
```

Comment: @DaNubCake if you provide a complete data structure I can narrow my solution to fit your requirements if you like.